# Javascriptのライブラリーで画像から色を抽出するcolor-thiefで毎回RGB(144, 161, 166)と同じ色が取得される。

Tags: javascript

画像から主に使用される色を取得したく[color-thies](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/#getting-started)と言うライブラリーを使用したいのですが上手く動作しないです。

フロントエンドから使用したいのでCDNで読み込んでいます。

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/color-thief/2.3.0/color-thief.umd.js"></script>
```

それで公式ドキュメント通りに画像のパスではなく、画像タグを指定しているのですが返ってくる値が毎回同じです。

```
<script>
    const colorThief = new ColorThief();
    const img = document.querySelector('img');

    // Make sure image is finished loading
    if (img.complete) {
      colorThief.getColor(img);
    } else {
      image.addEventListener('load', function() {
        colorThief.getColor(img);
      });
    }
</script>
```

そして`console.log(colorThief.getColor(img));`で毎回返ってくる値を確認しているのですが、`[144, 161, 166]`が毎回配列になってどの画像でも同じ値が返ってきます。
画像のsrc等が外部からなのが原因なのでしょうか？

例：
https://img.youtube.com/vi/IcU5lh_EWvc/maxresdefault.jpg

ただローカルの画像パスでも試したのですが、結果は同じでした。
詳しい方、助けて頂けないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FAQ](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/#faq)にありますが別ドメインの画像だとCORSの制限を受けます。
FAQではプロキシを設置し緩いCORSポリシーを設定するか、テスト用にGoogleのプロキシサーバーの利用する方法が紹介されてます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。CORSの制限を受けるのですね。サーバ側で処理しようと思います。

Comment: FAQを読んだのですがimgタグに`crossorigin="anonymous"`を書けば解決するのでしょうか？

Comment: CORSが許可されてる画像なら解決するんじゃないかと思います。内部実装はHTML CanvasなのでMDNの記事が参考になるかと https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image